# Firebase - method returns undefined even though value is not undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I wrote a method using the Firebase API that should return the average of some numbers. The method works for the most part, but fails on the return. My alert(sum) returns the correct answer, but the method returns undefined for some reason.

```
function returnAverage ( keyName )
{
    myDataRef.child(keyDictionary[keyName]).once( 'value', function(dataSnapshot)
    {
        tempPermArray = dataSnapshot.val();
        var data = dataSnapshot.val();

        var sum = 0;
        for ( var entry in data['submissions'] )
        {
            sum += parseInt(data['submissions'][entry][0]);
        }
        sum /= returnSize(data['submissions']);

        alert( sum );
        return sum;
    });
}
```

When I create a new variable in the console and set it to 0, it returns 0. When I set that variable equal to this method's results, however, it changes its value to undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.once('value')` is an *asynchronous* function. The `return` statement you have in there is not for the `returnAverage` function but rather the inner function that you have passed as the second argument to `.once('value')`. For example, try this:

```
function returnAverage ( keyName )
{
  myDataRef.child(keyDictionary[keyName]).once( 'value', function(dataSnapshot) {
    ...
  }
  return 10;
}
```

and you'll see that the variable will be assigned the value 10.

The basic problem is that the value will have to be retrieved from the server, which takes a little while. You'll need to call your own function after the value has been retrieved to do whatever you'd like with it, or use a "promise" (see http://www.promisejs.org/).